# parse a csv with dynamic number of keys python

Tags: python

I am working on a script that reads data from a `csv` and puts it to a `dict`. My data is like below:

```
firstName    lastName    skill
alice        sparks      artist
mark         peters      sports
bob          stones      teacher
Chelsea
chester                  sports
```

and so on, the data is a `csv` that means in the above example, the spaces are actually comma's.

I want to parse this data into a csv column wise, the final dict must be like below:

```
{'firstName': ['alice', 'mark', 'bob'], 'lastName': ['sparks', 'peters', 'stones'], 'skill': ['artist', 'sports', 'teacher']}
```

in theory:

1. The first row becomes the keys in the dict
2. The other rows in that particular column become an array of values
3. The number of keys may vary from 2-40 so it should be dynamic (auto-detect) if it's possible.
4. As in the sample, it's possible that the columns would have less entries as compared to other columns

Is such thing possible in python?

I searched online everywhere I get row based results, but I need column wise and that to in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a pandas DataFrame's [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
d = df.to_dict('list')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `csv.DictReader()` and `dictionary.setdefault()`.

## Code:

```
csvf = csv.DictReader(open("test.csv","r"))

d = {}
for row in csvf:
    for header, item in row.items():
        d.setdefault(header, []).append(item)
```

## Output:

```
{'firstName': ['alice', 'mark', 'bob', 'Chelsea', 'chester'],
 'lastName': ['sparks', 'peters', 'stones', '', ''],
 'skill': ['artist', 'sports', 'teacher', '', 'sports']}
```

`DictReader()` returns an array of `OrderedDictionary`s in the forms of `(header, row[i])`, which is the perfect preface for your use case.  All you needed was a Dcitionary with default item type `list` and `append` to the list as you iterate through each row.

Comment: throws me an error one the line `for header, item in line.items():` stating `AttributeError: 'row' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: Did you use `row` or `line`? Your statement says `line.items()` but the error is for `row`.  If you want to rename your variables make sure you refactor consistently to my sample. You should only be 2 level deep in iteration, the first level is iterating throw the `row`s, and second is iterating through the `OrderedDictionary` items.  Try a `type()` on the error object to ensure you're expecting the correct object type.

Comment: yeah I renamed it to `line` instead of `row` forgot to swap the name in the code line while pasting, although changed it in the error message. Sorry for that

Comment: Are you still experiencing the same error? What is `type(line)` returning for you? Did it fail in your implementation or in my minimal example under your use case? Try my minimal example on your `csv` file first if you haven't already.  It works with the new data set you provided as well - I've updated the answer with the results.  It could also be originating from your `csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pandas for this:

```
# Convert DataFrame to Dictionary 
df_dict = df.to_dict()

# Now convert it to list of values 
for key,value in df_dict:
df_dict[key] = [value for key,value in df_dict[key].items()]

# Or you can directly use:
df_dict = df.to_dict("list")
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will also satisfy all your conditions including duplicates and empty values.

***Code:***

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {}
    a = []
    with open('sample.csv', 'r') as readf:
        enum_list = [line.rstrip('\n').split(',') for line in readf]
        for i,x in enumerate(enum_list):
            if i == 0:
                for val in x:
                    d[val] = []
                    a.append(val)
                continue
            for val in x:
                i = x.index(val)
                if val and val not in d[a[i]]:
                    d[a[i]].append(val)
    print(d)
```

***Output:***

```
{'first_name': ['alice', 'mark', 'bob', 'Chelsea', 'chester'], 'last_name': ['sparks', 'peters', 'stones'], 'skill': ['artist', 'sports', 'teacher']}
```